# Question about proof using epsilon delta for limits

Tags: real-analysis, epsilon-delta

When you use the epsilon delta method for proving limits and you face a problem of expressing $\delta$ as a function of $\epsilon$ only, I know that you have to put a restriction on $\vert{x-c}\vert$ to attain an inequality $\vert{x-c}\vert<1$ (1 is arbitrary). This will get us an expression relating $\delta$ with $\epsilon$. and We choose the smaller one of the two.

I understand this procedure, but not quite the reason why we use $\vert{x-c}\vert<1$ as the restriction in the first place. I guess we can use any other values, but wouldn't that result in different answers?

Also, what if we chose a restriction such as $\vert{x-c}\vert<0.0001$ (a small number). Would this still be okay?

For example, given $\epsilon>0$, we want to show that if $\vert{x-3}\vert<\delta$, then $\vert{\frac{2x+3}{4x-9}-3}\vert<1$

$\vert{\frac{2x+3}{4x-9}-3}\vert=\vert{\frac{10(x-3)}{4x-9}}\vert=\frac{10}{\vert{4x-9}\vert}\vert{x-3}\vert<\epsilon$

So if we place a restriction such that $\vert{x-3}\vert<1$, then $2<x<4$. Thus, $1<\vert{4x-9}\vert<7$. So if $\vert{x-3}\vert<1$, then $\vert{4x-9}\vert>1$.
Thus $\delta=min(1,\frac{\epsilon}{10}$).

However, if we chose the restriction $\vert{x-3}\vert<1/10$, then $13/5<\vert{4x-9}\vert<17/5$. Meaning that we would get $\vert{x-3}\vert<13\epsilon/50$.
So $\delta=min(1,\frac{13\epsilon}{50}$)

Comment: May I suggest that you add a specific example?

Comment: Intuitively, you should think of $\delta$ as being an arbitrary small number. Without going into too much detail, you might understand from the definition of the limit that the idea is to show that if one is small, so is the other. If $\delta$ is very large, this doesn't do us very much good in understanding the limit. $1$ is just a convenient, yet relatively small number.

Comment: @String Thanks you for your suggestion. I did.

Comment: @AlfredYerger Oh. Okay. But what if we put a restriction of $\vert{x-c}\vert<1/10$ as shown above. Or any smaller restriction. That changes the answer doesn't it?

Comment: @user143391 it may change the exact relation between $\epsilon$ and $\delta$, but the only thing that interests you is that if $\epsilon$ is small, so is $\delta$

Comment: @vonbrand So does that mean that the way of proving the limit is not unique since you can choose any arbitrarily small restriction?

Comment: @user143391 exactly

Comment: What the others have said. You got it.

Comment: @AlfredYerger Thank you!